# Chrome Keyboard Typing Sequence

Tags: google-chrome, script

I want to create a new shortcut that will run a keyboard script on the page.
for example when I do alt-g it will do [tab]+ type-"hi"+ enter.

Comment: look up [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: I'm looking for something more like chrome extension

Comment: [iMacros?](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) perhaps? never tried it myself though

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it with it

Comment: well, it depends on the page you are using maybe. Use "Record Macro" and it can remember how to fill in certain forms and buttons you press. Seems to work better on actual forms than it does in for example the Facebook chat though.

Comment: that exactly what I did, however the marco didn't contain any of the actions I did. just to make sure I ran it but it didn't do nothing obviously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23656/discussion-between-allman-and-guy-ephraim).